# How to save boot.log between reboots?

Tags: linux, boot, logs

How do you save the `/var/log/boot.log` between reboots? Or, more specifically, how can you just have boots be appended to that file? I have an issue with a kernel that I am running and need to be able to preserve the boot.log when I boot up into a working kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my answer; but it requires the use of `systemd`.

One can enable persistent journal logging by creating `/var/log/journald/`; once this has been done one can view long term journal logs using `journalctl`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official way to do this that I've ever seen using either `rsyslogd` or `logrotate`. One easy way to do this though that comes to mind would be to create a `@reboot` crontab entry that could backup the `boot.log` file prior to rebooting.

#### Example

Add the following to your system's `/etc/crontab` file.

```
@reboot cp -p /var/log/boot.log /var/log/boot.log.$(date +%F_%R)
```

This will create files named like this under `/var/log/`.

- boot.log.2013-12-29_03:29
- boot.log.2013-12-29_21:30

The time/date stamps on the file when you `ls -l` these files will be the original info. The `cp -p` will preserve this.

This approach will pile files up on you over time so you might want to only keep say the last 10 or so. You can add additional `@reboot` rules, say something like this to also trim these files.

```
@reboot [[ $(ls -1r /var/log/boot.log.* | wc -l) -gt 10 ]] \
    && ls -1r /var/log/boot.log.* | tail -n +10 | xargs rm
```

The above will check that we have more than 10 `boot.log.*` to start. If we do then it will list the files out in reverse order of creation time, and then filter out the most recent 10, and delete the rest.

#### Details

This bit will return the number of `boot.log.*` are currently present.

```
$(ls -1r /var/log/boot.log.* | wc -l)
```

This will check if that number is greater than 10.

```
[[ $(...) -gt 10 ]]
```

If there are more than 10 files, then we'll call the remove command.

```
.... && ls -1r /var/log/boot.log.* ... xargs rm
```

#### References

- [Linux Execute Cron Job After System Reboot](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/)

Comment: @josten - you could adapt it and create a cronjob that runs based on time then, perhaps every couple of minutes. The cronjob could check to see if there is already a backup of the current boot.log, if not then back it up, otherwise do nothing. Look here for examples: http://team.macnn.com/drafts/crontab_defs.html

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but I want to add to the answer that if you are using systemd's journalctl for logging, you should edit the /etc/systemd/journal.conf file. Add:

storage=persistant